# Qt - How To access the MainWindow from another child Window or Widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a college project using QT and in that project I am stuck at one point . That is , i want to access the main Window from another window or widget by the means of a push button but the Main Window object has no functions like setModel() or exec() which are used to access another window or widget . Please Help .

Comment: When you create any child widget you can pass parent in the constructor. And in Child widget you can use parentWidget() to get the pointer of parent.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a signal from the from the child window and connect it to a slot from the main window. When you press the button you emit the signal which is linked to the slot that is implemented in the main window.
You can see more about these here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html